# Keeping one column in a table using ng-repeat the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that is pulling data from a json file and populating td with ng-repeat. However, I want my first column (Line #) to stay the same. For example just 1,2,3,4 to represent which phone line the customer is on, and the rest of the data to be populated with the ng-repeat. I've been researching and have not been able to find anything any help is appreciated. Code is below.

```
        <tr>
            <th>Line #</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone #</th>
            <th>Range</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy: 'id' | limitTo: 4" ng-class="{ 'alert-danger' : customer.in == 'no', 'alert-success' : customer.in == 'yes', 'alert-warning' : customer.in == 'unknown' }">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.phoneNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.in}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="modal-close" ng-click="toggleModal()">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) exposes an `$index` property that will return the current index of the array.  So your HTML could look like:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy: 'id' | limitTo: 4" ng-class="{ 'alert-danger' : customer.in == 'no', 'alert-success' : customer.in == 'yes', 'alert-warning' : customer.in == 'unknown' }">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.phoneNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.in}}</td>
    </tr>
```